# Getting my Java program to display images through drag and drop

Tags: java, image, drag-and-drop, image-manipulation, jframe

I am trying to get my program to display an image after it is dragged over, but I dont really have a good idea of how to do this.

Example:  There is an image on your desktop, photo.jpg . You would take that, drag it over into a java JFrame, and the contents of that image (the photo iteself) would display.

From there I would like to be able to play with the size ability of the photo, but first step first, I dont know how to approach getting it to display in the JFrame.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but have you worked through the related Swing tutorials already? http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html - edit: Hmm appears that's mostly (only?) related to in app Drag&Drop..

Comment: I have, but I needed to understand how to do the part about the image more than the drag and drop part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the image (I didn't think you were asking about the drag-and-drop feature, if that was the part you were asking about, sorry.), you can either push the image into an ImageIcon and display it in a JLabel as described [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm)

Or you can mess around with using `Graphics#drawImage` methods in `paintComponent` to draw `Images`.
Something along the lines of (as a *very* basic example):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
{
    super.paintComponent(page);
    page.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

I give a more detailed example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051408/jpanel-with-image-background/4051708#4051708).