# Java: How to add a compoment on top of an another (ex JLabel to JLabel) from Gui Builder?

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel

I want to drag a Jlabel into another on gui builder but it doesn't set the JLabel as a container. Any ideas?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"*   Try something.  Get back to us when you have a *specific* question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jLabel isn't a container, it's a component. If you want to add multiple things to something then something should be a jPanel.

Create a jPanel and then add the two labels inside the panel at the positions you want.

Comment: Ok but then how can I insert an image on the panel? I wanted to be shown on the gui builder because I'm making a sudoku game and I want to put them exactly on position.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051408/jpanel-with-image-background